# How to display non-English language gotten by Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, translation

I'm getting some facebook posts that have a mixture of English and and a non-English language (Khmer to be exact).

Here's how the non-English is displayed when I print the data to screen or save it to file: \u178a\u17c2\u179b\u1787\u17b6\u17a2\u17d2. I would rather have it display as ឈឹម បញ្ចពណ៌ (Note: this is not a translation of the previous unicode.)

Comment: Which python version and which OS? How do you get the data from facebook? Do you decode it from utf-8?

Comment: 2.7.9, Mac. No, I'm not decoding it from utf-8. When I try, I get an error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 268: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you add your input when you tried to write a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it:

```
print(u'\u1787\u17b6\u17a2\u17d2') #python3
print u'\u1787\u17b6\u17a2\u17d2'  #python2.7
```

Output: ជាអ្

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to save the info in a file:

```
import codecs

string = 'ឈឹម បញ្ចពណ៌'
with codecs.open('yourfile', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm I added:

1. (at top) # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
2. import sys
   reload(sys)
   sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
3. s = json.dumps(posts['data'],ensure_ascii=False)
4. json_file.write(s.decode('utf-8'))